# Using Selenium to scrape webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a google scholar page with 'show more' button. I understand from my previous question that it is not a html but a javascript and there are several ways to scrape such pages. I tries selenium and tried the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_path = r"....path....."
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=TBcgGIIAAAAJ&hl=en")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[13]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/button/span/span[2]').click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

papers = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'gsc_a_tr'})

for paper in papers:
    title = paper.find('a',{'class':'gsc_a_at'}).text
    author = paper.find('div',{'class':'gs_gray'}).text
    journal = [a.text for a in paper.select("td:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)")]
    
       
    print('Paper Title:', title, '\nAuthor:', author, '\nJournal:', journal)
```

The browser now clicks the 'show more' button and displays the entire page. But, I am still getting the information only for the first 20 papers. I dont understand why. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the new elements haven't completely loaded in when your program checks the website. Try importing time and then sleeping for a few minutes. Like this (I removed the headless features so you can see the program work):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=TBcgGIIAAAAJ&hl=en")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("gsc_bpf_more").click()
time.sleep(4)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

papers = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'gsc_a_tr'})

for paper in papers:
    title = paper.find('a', {'class': 'gsc_a_at'}).text
    author = paper.find('div', {'class': 'gs_gray'}).text
    journal = [a.text for a in paper.select("td:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)")]

    print('Paper Title:', title, '\nAuthor:', author, '\nJournal:', journal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=TBcgGIIAAAAJ&hl=en")

# Awkward method
# Loading all available articles and then iterating over them
for i in range(1, 3):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#gsc_bpf_more').click()
    # waits until elements are loaded
    time.sleep(3)

# Container where all data located
for result in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_t'):
    title = result.find_element_by_css_selector('.gsc_a_at').text
    authors = result.find_element_by_css_selector('.gsc_a_at+ .gs_gray').text
    publication = result.find_element_by_css_selector('.gs_gray+ .gs_gray').text
    print(title)
    print(authors)
    print(publication)
    # just for separating purpose
    print()
```

Part of the output:

```
Tax/subsidy policies in the presence of environmentally aware consumers
S Bansal, S Gangopadhyay
Journal of Environmental Economics and Management 45 (2), 333-355

Choice and design of regulatory instruments in the presence of green consumers
S Bansal
Resource and Energy economics 30 (3), 345-368
```